# System Stack Error for Radiant 1.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

After installing Radiant 1.1.0, I can get DEMO site running. But after viewing a few of pages (public pages or admin pages), I got those errors.

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

Rendered rescues/_trace (1.4ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (1.1ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I changed my ruby stack size and even reinstalled my system but still can't fix the errors. I didn't encounter any issues when I was with radiant 1.0.1.

I am using

```
rvm 1.16.17 (stable)
brew installed GCC /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3
mysql-5.5.27

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 286) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/harry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@test1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/harry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/harry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@test1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/harry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@test1
     - /Users/harry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I have spent 2 weeks but still can't sort it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
rvm install ree-head
rvm use ree-head
script/server
```

now, you can inspect problem

for ex:

```
  SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  /home/web/.rvm/rubies/ree-head/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:212:in `dup'
  /home/web/.rvm/rubies/ree-head/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:212:in `initialize'
  /home/web/.rvm/gems/ree-head/bundler/gems/radiant-7cc8f6e90d98/app/models/radiant/config.rb:121:in `cache_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursive call somewhere (maybe in your models).  Posting some code would help pinpoint the problem.

You may have accidentally overwritten a core ruby class, have a typo in a function, wrote a recursive association, or a number of other possibilities.